# How can a PopUp get the styles from the main page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, modal-dialog

I have a PopUp opened by

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog
```

but the content of this Pop Up hasn't any styles of the Sharepoint Portal. (It hasn't access to javascript of the main page, too). It seems that is because SP uses iframes to open it.

How can the Pop Up get the styles from the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint modal dialogs use the same MasterPage as the Portal. Most of the styles are hidden using CSS tag i.e. s4-notdlg. If you search for this tag under master page, any styles under this will not be displayed on Modal Dialog.

You should either create PopupMaster.master for your popup pages, as modifying this tag will also effect Modal Dialogs used by SharePoint by default. Or you can also create a custom Master Page for Portal and modify as per your need.